# When will Salesforce SOS will be available for EU based Clusters?

Tags: servicecloud, feature-activation

As subject says - When will this feature be available for the EU based Salesforce instances. 
http://www.salesforce.com/service-cloud/features/sos/

Comment: Where does it say that is not available to EU instances?

Comment: I don't know. But I know for sure that it's not yet available.

Answer (score 0):

SOS is available to any instance regardless of the location but licenses need to be provisioned. You will need to contact your AE.